# Zebra RFID API TagData.getEventTimestamp() returns null from RFD8500

Tags: rfid

I am using the Zebra RFID API 3 SDK 2.0.1.34 to scan RFID tags with the RFD8500 scanner. In my implementation of the `eventReadNotify()` method from the `RfidEventsListener` interface, I am extracting the tag ID, RSSI, and timestamp fields. However, the timestamp, which I am trying to get by using the `TagData.getTagEventTimeStamp()` method, is always null.

```
            for (int i = 0; i < tagArray.getLength(); i++) {
                TagData tag = tagArray.getTags()[i];
                Log.i("RFID", "Tag ID = " + tag.getTagID());
                Log.w ("RFID", "RSSI " + tag.getPeakRSSI());
                Log.w("RFID", "timestamp " + tag.getTagEventTimeStamp());
                this.dispatchEvent("TagEvent", tag.getTagID());
            }
```

```
2021-07-20 15:45:16.563 4972-5115/com.radargunn.dev I/RFID: Tag ID = 309406C9D820900000000000
2021-07-20 15:45:16.563 4972-5115/com.radargunn.dev W/RFID: RSSI -51
2021-07-20 15:45:16.563 4972-5115/com.radargunn.dev W/RFID: timestamp null
2021-07-20 15:45:16.563 4972-5115/com.radargunn.dev I/RFID: Tag ID = 30540BDF402E84C000000002
2021-07-20 15:45:16.563 4972-5115/com.radargunn.dev W/RFID: RSSI -62
2021-07-20 15:45:16.564 4972-5115/com.radargunn.dev W/RFID: timestamp null
```

Is there some configuration setting I need to change to get this to work?

Comment: Hi , Could you please share your code to connect and status notificaton? I am also developing application related to zebra rfid scanner , I am able to connect with device successfully but code is not scanning barcode.

Comment: Hi @Westy have you got a chance to check my comment?

Comment: Hi @vishvakapadia. Sorry, I never got an answer to this, so I just gave up. The timestamp we are using is just the current time when our app sees the tag.

Comment: Could you please share your code of scanning ?